# Navigation to Pivot Item

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, c++-cx

I have two different pages with a pivot element on each page. All I want is to navigate from one page to a specific pivot item on the other page. How to pass and handle navigation information (like item index) for the NavigatedFrom and NavigatedTo method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **Windows Phone XAML/WinRT** apps you can provide a parameter in the `Navigate` method:

```
Frame->Navigate(AnotherPage::typeid, 42);
```

and in case of passing '0' you need to use implicit boxing, like this

```
Frame->Navigate(AnotherPage::typeid, safe_cast<Platform::Object^>(0));
```

Finally you can read it in `OnNavigatedTo`:

```
protected:
void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs^ e) override
{ 
    auto parameter = (int)e->Parameter; 
}
```

Have a look at

http://mikaelkoskinen.net/winrt-xaml-navigating-from-page-to-page-how-it-differs-from-windows-phone-7/

For **Windows Phone Silverlight** apps (C# only) you need to put your parameter into the query string of the navigation URI and read it in the `OnNavigatedTo` method.

Comment: I see, thanks for your help. Am I right in assuming that, since OnNavigatedTo is called every time a navigation to this page occurs, I have to provide a parameter on the app's start up - because the pivot page is gonna get loaded in my project first - and extend the method itself to handle the initial pivot item accordingly? If so what would be the best way to accomplish this, e.g. passing and checking for a key/value pair?

Comment: one bit of a question: why are you refusing my edit of your answer? i made changes to the code samples because - in fact - it wasn't c++/cx related, instead it is c# code and therefore (considering the topic's tags) it is false!